# concat with object in same list

Tags: javascript, object, concatenation

I want to concatenate the contents of one object with another, but within the same list/command:

```
var MyVar = {
    options: {
        option1: "foo",
        option2: "bar",
        option3: "It's not kung "+options.option1+", but kung fu",
    }
}
```

this doesn't work, any hints on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: *"what I'm doing wrong here"*. You are trying to do something that is not possible.

Comment: thanks for linking to the answer!

Answer (score 1):

options.option1 is not defined yet at the point you are using it.

```
var MyVar = {
  options: {
    option1: "foo",
    option2: "bar"
  }
};

MyVar.options.option3 = "It's not kung "+MyVar.options.option1+", but kung fu";
```

should work as intended.

Note that this is not dynamic (option3 does not change on changes on option1). If you want dynamic behaviour, you find solutions here: [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)